# ASP.net Core: Is it normal to call method of different controller from view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 controllers: `FirstController` and `SecondController`.

First controller contains GET method `GetFirstData` for send some data.

Second controller contains similar method `GetSecondData` for send different data.

I also have 2 views Index.cshtml for each controller.

I know that call `GetFirstData` method from Index.cshtml view is normal. But is it good to call `GetSecondData` method from Index.cshtml of `FirstController`? E.g. using AJAX with `@Url.Action("GetSecondData", "Second")`

Comment: There's no problem doing this. If others  can follow your code then there shouldn't be any problems. However, if your application is very large and you find yourself doing very many of these cross controller calls, it may be time to reconsider how your controllers are organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do like this. If you are using Ajax to call that method, there wouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Yep, it's not a problem, just want to ensure in correctness of this call. Thank you

Comment: Ohk understand..always ready to help

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that for sure, you can simply use the controller methods as web calls by `AJAX` but I would recommend that:

1-If `GetSecondData` is being used by many `views` across various `controllers`, I would recommend you separate it in a separate `controller`.

Why? Because it seems like this method is more general than being bound to a specific `controller` with much of `views` and `Actions`

2-I would also recommend you separate the `AJAX function` in a separate JS file and include it in the `views` which are interested in the `function`.

Comment: I use `Controller-Service-Repository architecture` and due to FK between tables i want to do this calls (your solution now not great for me, i think, it will cause duplicating of the some classes). Ofcourse, i can receive in `First service` repository of the `Second`, implement some method in `First controller` and call it, but it looks bad: method `GetSecondControllerData` in `First controller` looks really bad, again. But, you gave me another solution, thank you for this, i think it can be useful for me someday..